# Route failing using STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, railstutorial.org, sti

First SO post, but I've read so many. I'm new to Rails and building first site since studying Hartl's RailsTutorial.

My issue is routing using STI. I believe the routes are set up correctly, but the subclass Kid doesn't find a "show" route.

**Class inheritance using STI**

> class User < ActiveRecord::Base
>
> class Kid < User

**Kid Controller**

> def show
>
> > @kid = Kid.find(params[:id])
>
> end

**User Controller create**

```
def create
@user = User.new(params[:user])
if @user.save
  flash[:success] = "Welcome to kidtunes!"
  if (@user.type = "Kid")
    ***redirect_to @kid***
  else
redirect_to @parent
  end
else
  render 'new'
end
```

**routes.rb**

> resources :users, :kids, :parents
>
> root to: 'static_pages#home'
>
> match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
>
> match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
>
> match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'

**Results in:**

```
kids_new    GET    /kids/new(.:format)         kids#new
  users     GET    /users(.:format)            users#index
            POST   /users(.:format)            users#create
   new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)        users#new
  edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)   users#edit
   user     GET    /users/:id(.:format)        users#show
            PUT    /users/:id(.:format)        users#update
            DELETE /users/:id(.:format)        users#destroy
   kids     GET    /kids(.:format)             kids#index
            POST   /kids(.:format)             kids#create
new_kid     GET    /kids/new(.:format)         kids#new
   edit_kid GET    /kids/:id/edit(.:format)    kids#edit
    kid     GET    /kids/:id(.:format)         kids#show
            PUT    /kids/:id(.:format)         kids#update
            DELETE /kids/:id(.:format)         kids#destroy
parents     GET    /parents(.:format)          parents#index
            POST   /parents(.:format)          parents#create
 new_parent GET    /parents/new(.:format)      parents#new
edit_parent GET    /parents/:id/edit(.:format) parents#edit
 parent     GET    /parents/:id(.:format)      parents#show
            PUT    /parents/:id(.:format)      parents#update
            DELETE /parents/:id(.:format)      parents#destroy
   root            /                           static_pages#home
   help            /help(.:format)             static_pages#help
contact            /contact(.:format)          static_pages#contact
 signup            /signup(.:format)           users#new
```

**Error**
I get the following on redirect_to @kid

ActionController::ActionControllerError (Cannot redirect to nil!):
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:16:in `create'

I feel like I've checked everything I can check, but I'm still missing something. @kid should properly redirect to the kids#show route. I'm not sure if I have a poorly crafted single table inheritance or a basic routing issue.

thanks in advance.
-John

**Form**

This form is used in users/new.html.erb and it creates the User.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span5 offset2">
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

<%= f.label :fname, "First Name" %>
<%= f.text_field :fname %>

<%= f.label :lname, "Last Name" %>
<%= f.text_field :lname %>

<%= f.label :email %>
<%= f.text_field :email %>

<%= f.label :type, "Are you a Kid or Parent?" %>
<%= f.select :type, [['Kid','Kid'],['Parent','Parent']] %>

<%= f.label :password %>
<%= f.password_field :password %>

<%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

<%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: if (@user.type == "Kid")
     ***redirect_to @kid***
  else

Comment: Thanks, noob error on my part. Unfortunately still not redirecting.  Fails at "redirect_to @kid" "with Cannot redirect to nil!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you defined/assigned values to the `@kid` or `@parent` variables? If not, they will be `nil`, and you'll get the `cannot redirect to nil` error you've included in your question.

Please include the full code for the `create` action. Otherwise we're left to trust (rather than read for ourselves) precisely what's happening in the redirect.

Your redirects might also need some work. For example, you could do:

```
if (@user.is_a? Kid)
  redirect_to kid_path(@user)
else
  redirect_to parent_path(@user)
end
```

...or something very similar to that.

Comment: That's it!  My redirects were poorly formed.  Thank you very much to everyone who offered advice.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I noticed is that you're using `=` instead of `==`:

```
if (@user.type = "Kid")
```

I think it's nicer to test it like that:

```
if @user.is_a? Kid
```

Can you show us how you set `@kid` and `@parent`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that better method.  I edit the post to include the form I am using to create the user.  Kid inherits from User and I use the :type field to determine if the user is a "Kid" or "Parent". So I'm not creating instances of Kid and Parent. However I do want to have different show pages for Kid and Parent. Unfortunately it doesn't see a route to kid#shows (@kid).